# Starting a shell script in a new Terminal using python and get exit code

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, subprocess

I'm currently trying to run a shell script via python in a new terminal. So far it is working right now, my issue now is that I also need the exit code of that shell script. Depending on successful execution or not the script returns different exit codes and I need to get them so I can continue working with them in python. My code looks like that right now:

```
    process = subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal', '-x', './myscript.sh'])
    text = process.communicate()[0]
    exit_code = process.returncode
    print(text, exit_code)
```

I probably also need a wait function, because the script needs few seconds to finish execution. Does anyone know how I can do all that?

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) suggest using `subprocess.run`.

Comment: you can add a `wait()` function

Comment: The requirement to run in a new terminal is probably bogus. Many beginners want this, but usually it's better to run the subprocess quietly, and capture its output in Python. Then if you need to display some or all of it, simply `print` it. Of course, there _are_ situations where you need a new window, but those then tend to have additional complications. Do you need to interact with the process running in the terminal? And, does Python need to interact with it programmatically?

Comment: @tripleee I need a new terminal because the script that is executed will run until it get terminated. Also the terminal from where the script is started is also running a program and because i need both outputs I need to start the script in a separate terminal

Comment: The usual solution to that is to run it in the background, with output to a log file which you can examine at will from any terminal window, text editor, or etc.

Comment: @tripleee how could I do that? Right now the process runs into the timeout or stops my application from where the subprocess was called

Comment: Which timeout? Run the entire Python process in the background. If you need the process to run in parallel with your Python code, provide an example which actually implements that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @tjm3772 mentioned in the comments, [subprocess.run](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) is probably what you want. e.g.

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.run(['bash', './bash_script.sh'], capture_output=True, timeout=120)
text = process.stdout
exit_code = process.returncode
print(text, exit_code)
```

Both `capture_output` and `timeout` are optional. `timeout` is in seconds. As you'll see from the docs, there are many other options if required.

`run` returns a [CompletedProcess](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess) object representing a process that has finished. So no need to worry about (in your Python code) how long your shell script may take etcetera. (Other than perhaps wanting a `timeout` as mentioned above to cover the possible scenario of your script hanging/taking too long.)